# How to add a json object to existing json array in groovy

Tags: groovy

Below is my Json array and I want to add a new json object to it in jenkins pipeline groovy script.

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Sandeep",
        "Age": "25"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Krishna",
        "Age": "26"
    }
]
```

Expected response

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Sandeep",
        "Age": "25"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Krishna",
        "Age": "26"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Ramesh",
        "Age": "30"
    }
]
```

Comment: use the readJSON function and then just add the one list to the other (the + operator should work)

Comment: https://groovy-lang.org/json.html